# How to do authorization without authentication in Spring Security 5

Tags: authentication, spring-security, authorization

I'm new in Spring Security. I'm trying to integrate Spring Security in my web application.

We have our own authentication process and this cannot be modified. Nevertheless, once the user succeeds this process, it's loaded in the session, including roles.

What we are trying to achieve is to make use of this information for the authorization process of Spring Security, that's to say, to force it to get the roles from the user session instead of picking it up through the authentication-provider.

Is there any way to achieve this in Spring Security 5?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Just configure your spring security as you are going to use http basic authentication.

And then in when you complete your custom login, set this so it is available to Spring security for authorization.

```
Authentication authentication = new 
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("username", null, authoritiesOfUser);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, 
                     SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
```

Spring security has a filter called `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`, it will automatically take what you set above, put it in the http session with its own key and then repopulate `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` on subsequent requests.